# Display directories in tkinter

Tags: tkinter, tk-toolkit, directory-structure

I am developing a program which has it's own special folder with sub folders and I want to know if there is a way of displaying all the folders and files in my window like my own custom file browser but I don't mean like the tkinter filedialog.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't want to use the built-in versions of things and instead desire to build it yourself to get extra control? Consider using the [Treeview](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/tkinter.ttk.html#tkinter.ttk.Treeview); you'll have to provide code to populate the contents, but you can do a multi-column view easily with it where the first column is a hierarchic tree. That's the sort of thing you want when doing an Explorer-like interface. (If you were using the Tcl bindings to Tk, I'd point you to a specific script of interest in the standard widget demonstrator that shows the basics of doing this sort of thing — the “directory browser tree” under “Listboxes and Trees” — but I don't know the Python equivalents well enough to do the same.)

Answer (score 0):

Tkinter does not provides this kind of widget. However, [Tix (Tk Interface Extension)](http://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.tix.html) has this kind of widgets: `tix.DirList`, `tix.FileSelectBox`... (see [tix documentation](http://tix.sourceforge.net/dist/current/docs/tix-book/filesel.tex.html) for pictures). In your case, I woud use `tix.ExFileSelectBox`.

```
import tkinter.tix
root = tkinter.tix.Tk()

fs = tkinter.tix.ExFileSelectBox(root, directory="/the/folder/your/want")
fs.pack()
```

Comment: I don't want a directory selector I want a way to make my own custom directory browser.

Comment: What is the difference you make between a directory browser and a directory selector whith no action bound on selection ?

Comment: I want to make one with a design like the windows file explorer.